# How to access object in a list - Scala

Tags: scala

My code is as follows:

```
class HuffmanNode(val chars: String, val occurrences: Int) {
  override def toString: String = "{" + chars + "|" + occurrences + "}"

  def absoluteValue: Int = occurrences

  def getChars: String = chars

  def getOccurrences: String = occurrences.toString
}

object HuffmanNode {
  def apply(chars: String, occurrences: Int): HuffmanNode = {
    new HuffmanNode(chars, occurrences)
  }
}
```

I'm trying to create a list of `HuffmanNode`, e.g.:

```
val PQ: List[HuffmanNode] = List(HuffmanNode("a", 3), HuffmanNode("b", 3))
```

How do I access the methods inside the HuffmanNode?

I tried doing this:

```
PQ(0).getChars
```

But I get an error saying, `unable to resolve symbol getChars`.

What could the problem be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not compile. If I would hazard a guess I would imagine that you are using a list of the singleton instead of an instance of the class (the singleton does not have a getChars method, only the apply).

Comment: Right! I was doing what you just said

Comment: @Vasu, if the answer helps, you should mark it as Accepted

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @Assaf Mendelson you refer to the singleton object instead of instance of the class.

In order to fix you code you should create instance of the class instead like:

```
  val PQ = List(HuffmanNode("blabla", 2))
  val chars = PQ(0).getChars // now compiles
```

Comment: Actually the whole point of having an object with an apply is not to use new yourself, you should instead use val PQ = List(HuffmanNode("blabla", 2))

Answer (score 0):

If you change code as I suggested in edit, there is no problem to invoke `getChars` method:

```
class HuffmanNode(val chars: String, val occurrences: Int) {
  override def toString: String = "{" + chars + "|" + occurrences + "}"

  def absoluteValue: Int = occurrences

  def getChars: String = chars

  def getOccurrences: String = occurrences.toString
}

object HuffmanNode {
  def apply(chars: String, occurrences: Int): HuffmanNode = {
    new HuffmanNode(chars, occurrences)
  }
}

val PQ: List[HuffmanNode] = List(HuffmanNode("a", 3), HuffmanNode("b", 3))

PQ(1).getChars
```

I got:

```
PQ: List[HuffmanNode] = List({a|3}, {b|3})

res0: String = b
```

However I needed (just to test) remove keyword override from `absoluteValue` method.